# Always Return False - OOP Php

Tags: php

I'm new in `php` environment and learning how to do coding in simple `OOP` format. I'm about to test my `function` in my `class` to see if the user is already registered.

here's my: `testController.php`

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_DEPRECATED);

require_once('test.php');
$test = new test();

$email = isset($_POST['emailAdd']) ? $_POST['emailAdd'] : '';

if ($test->emailExist($email)) {
    echo "TRUE";
}else {
    echo "FALSE";
}

?>
```

My class: `test.php`

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_DEPRECATED);
require_once('dbConnectClass.php');

class test{
    private $db;
    public $getEmail;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new dbConnectClass();
        $this->db->connectDatabase();
    }

    public  function emailExist($email)
    {
        $getEmail = $email;
        $sql = "SELECT EmailAddress FROM useryayong WHERE `EmailAddress` = '$email' ";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect,$sql);

            $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                // user exist
                return true;
            } else {
                // user not exist
                return false;
            }

    }

}
```

Here's my: `dbConnectClass.php`

```
<?php
//INCLUDE DB
require('dbConnect.php');

class dbConnectClass{

    //VAR Connect
    public $connect;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public function __construct(){}    

    //DESTRUCTOR
    public function __destruct(){}

    //METHOD - CONNECT TO DATBASE
    public function connectDatabase(){

       $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,
                                       DB_USER,
                                       DB_PASSWORD,
                                       DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));

            //SET CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("Database connection failed");
            }else {
                return $this->connect;    
            }

    }

    //METHOD - CLOSE DATABASE CONNECTION
    public function closeDatabaseCon(){
        mysqli_close($this->connect);
    }    

}//END CLASS
?>
```

TABLE : dummy values
[image: table]

POSTMAN
[image: post]

In my table `dards@yahoo.com` exist. So it should return TRUE.

Comment: You haven't assigned `$db` to a class property of `test`.

Comment: Sir, if it's ok, can you post your answer to that specific line only. I doubt my error is in this line `$sql = "SELECT EmailAddress FROM useryayong WHERE `EmailAddress` ='.$email' ";`

Comment: is the email stored on your database table?

Comment: Yes, It is stored. But it always return FALSE.

Comment: I will add some photos.

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor function to this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new dbConnectClass();
    $this->db->connectDatabase();
}
```

And there's an error on your SQL syntax. Remove the `.` from in front of `$email`.

```
"SELECT EmailAddress FROM useryayong WHERE `EmailAddress` = '$email'";
```

Comment: Thanks, It really works! I will accept your answer after 5 mins countdown. :) Thank you.

Comment: SIr, can you help me out, I always get FALSE result. I try by using `POSTMAN`

Comment: use the exact query as I have answered above.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove `isset($_POST['emailAdd']) ? $_POST['emailAdd'] : '';` from `$email` in my `test.php` .